# SES PHP newsletter cronjob mail sending loop

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I just started Amazon SES and successfully configured. Actually I purchased for sending news letter as well as member status for my site.

My Site contains about 18000 Users. I want to run a cron job every saturday evening and send them the newest updations and their current status.

Can I fulfil the requirement with Amazon SES ?

Any problem if I looped these users in a mail query ? As I am a new bee to this , any one can please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it depends. As a new user to ses, i noticed that you are allow to send 10k emails per 24 hours. you have 18k. Could problem yes.

I tried once by sending 5k emails and i got time out issue with php. So i think you need to split 18k into small portion i guess...